# Is it necessary to delete a database before restoring the backup in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

As a rule, I always drop the database, and then create a new one and only after that restore a dump file. But I'm wondering, is it necessary to do?

For example, if I lose some data and begin to restore my database, why I cannot just to restore it, like in MS SQL, without deleting it first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the first few lines of the dump -- Does it say `DROP DATABASE` or anything like that?

(There are many options on mysqldump that control whether drops, creates, etc, are emitted into the dump, so there is no single answer to this question.)